# how to convert two different tables data into one single .csv file in oracle appex

Tags: sql-server, csv, oracle11g, oracle-apex, export-to-csv

I have two tables in database. I want to create a .csv file to maintain all activities done on that two tables. I need help in converting these two tables data into one single .csv file in oracle apex.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to export the data to a CSV?

- write an SQL select query to link both the tables together. If you need help with this, let us know
- create a Report and enter the SQL in the source
- go to **Report Attributes**, there is an option called **Enable CSV Output**. Make sure this is set to **Yes**
- Run the page, there should be a hyperlink or button beneath the report which exports the file.

Comment: I have a form displaying two tables related data. Now when am updating thes fields through application's form, i want to maintain a activity log. Which fields are updating,bywhom,what.. like this. But this has to be done automatically in background and has to create this .csv file.

Comment: if possible can u give small example for one table data to convert into .csv file using sql code in oracle apex.

Comment: @user2089647 It seems that your actual problem is not really the export to a csv file, as what Rohan described perfectly covers this in case of a classic report. You want to have a full-fledged auditing/journalling on your tables and then report on this. Please accurately present your problem in your OP, and don't mix questions together.